# set Jenkins Pipeline master branch priority

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a a lot of Multibranch Pipeline ( more than 200 ) , Is there any option to make sure that the **master** branch will have higher priority than other branches ?

I am working with AWS configuration , and sometime there is a small queue , it would be great that **master** branches will run first.

Comment: I've never used this, but maybe this plugin will be helpful to you: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin  I'm not sure if it will meet your needs, but that is the first thing that came to my head.

Comment: Thanks but , I don’t think this one is useful